# Why does interval function not execute unless for loop is removed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

In below code, the previous render of my drawing in canvas is removed every 50 milliseconds per calling the function clearRect(), however only works when the for loop to draw vertices is removed from "moveVerts()". The result I'm getting with including the loop is that new drawings are rendered on top of the previous drawing, even though function is called to clear the canvas 2d context. First attempt at Javascript.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var xCoord = [0, 176, 220, 259, 284, 310, 317, 310, 289, 262, 244, 219, 0, 0, 156, 198, 231, 246, 246, 231, 209, 182, 145, 0];
var yCoord = [0, 0, 8, 24, 45, 87, 133, 176, 214, 240, 251, 262, 262, 240, 240, 227, 200, 165, 116, 89, 72, 63, 59, 59];
var numCoord = xCoord.length;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "0";
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
for ( i = 0; i < numCoord; i++) {
  ctx.lineTo(xCoord[i], yCoord[i]);
}

ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

setInterval("moveVerts()", 50)
// make it squiggle
function moveVerts() {
  var mScale = (Math.random() - .5) * 12;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  for ( i = 0; i < numCoord; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(xCoord[i] + mScale, yCoord[i] + mScale);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
```

Comment: Change `setInterval("moveVerts()", 50)` to `setInterval(moveVerts, 50)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call

```
ctx.beginPath();
```

in your `moveVerts` function as well. Without, the canvas keeps the path you're drawing, appends new lines every time, and then strokes the entire thing.

Fixed code (also the things that others mentioned):

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var xCoord = [0, 176, 220, 259, 284, 310, 317, 310, 289, 262, 244, 219, 0, 0, 156, 198, 231, 246, 246, 231, 209, 182, 145, 0];
var yCoord = [0, 0, 8, 24, 45, 87, 133, 176, 214, 240, 251, 262, 262, 240, 240, 227, 200, 165, 116, 89, 72, 63, 59, 59];
var numCoord = Math.min(xCoord.length, yCoord.length);

ctx.lineWidth = "0";
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

moveVerts();
setInterval(moveVerts, 50);

// make it squiggle
function moveVerts() {
  var mScale = (Math.random() - .5) * 12;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ctx.moveTo(xCoord[0] + mScale, yCoord[0] + mScale);
  for (var i = 1; i < numCoord; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(xCoord[i] + mScale, yCoord[i] + mScale);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, and it is indeed working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable i is declared as global variable. Try using let. Example ( let i = 0; i < numCoord; i++)

Comment: While I agree global variables are bad practice, I don't see how it would be causing a critical error in this case.